# How can I add window Service in C#/ install it and Run exe(My Job.exe) through this Window Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation

Actually I want to run exe file(My Job.exe) Through window Service  in C# but window service should be started automatically when I start the Computer?

I have already added Window Service (MyService) manually. I have also setup project of My application where I also added this service so that I can also be installed when I install my Application.
I have serviceInstaller1 with property

```
StartType=Automatic;ServiceName=MyService.
```

I also have serviceProcessInstaller1 with Property

```
Account=LocalSystem;
```

When I run this my Applicationo gets installed but MyService don't get installed and I also not see it in Service of Computer Management.

Could any body please help me I already spend two days on it but not finding proper guidline. thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework you use? What VisualStudio do you use? On what OS will be service installed? Maybe u need to register service with InstallUtil.exe.

Comment: I am using .Net 4.0 with visual Studio 2010.service will be installed on Window XP but later on will also be install on Window 7 and 8.

Comment: http://cherupally.blogspot.in/2009/09/how-to-create-setup-project-to-install.html might help

Comment: @har har
nope, that cant help him because in VS2010 is not possible to create  setup project. You need to use InstallShield to create setup project and InstallShield must be purchased separately.

Comment: I have already created many Setup projects in VS2010 that's all work fine but never for window service..

Answer (score 0):

How is your application being installed? Did you create an installer (.msi file) for it? It sounds like you're trying to implement your own installer instead of using existing tool to do this.

I recommend [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/). It is a very powerful installer generator and has all the features you need in the free version, and more importantly, it's very easy to use. This tool lets you create an install wizard with the ability to patch and uninstall your software (including services, registry values, files, etc).

Comment: I have made new Setup project in VS2010 for that, through these steps Addd-> new Project -> setup and deployment ->Visual Studio Installer ->Setup project. When I Run this it run My Application but not the service I too included.

Answer (score 0):

I recently have one project with windows service in VS2010 and .Net 4.5 and user OS will be Windows Server 2008. I was unable to create fully functional installation a long time, and still i dont have, but request are changed so no need for installation file. But i can give you advice "How to do". 
If you don't have purchased version of InstallShield you need to find some other program for creating installation file. 
For installation you need just to copy you .exe output of service and one batch file witch will have next content:

```
@ECHO off

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" "%~dp0%<filename>.exe"

pause
```

and then you need to run with administration rights this batch file.
Both files (.exe and .bat) must be in same folder. 
You can delete `pause` command but then you will not see if registration of service was successfully.
Make sure that you have installed target .NET Framework on PC.

I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to run your exe file(My Job.exe) when the system starts up you could add your exe to the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows7/schedule-a-task).

*Is there any specific purpose for using a Windows service?*

The reason that I am saying this is that you have a wide variety of options to invoke you exe as follows

- Schedule based on common recurring events, i.e. When the computer starts or When a user logs on.
- Schedule based on the calendar, i.e. Daily, Weekly, Monthly, or One time.
- Advanced options like execution based on events, etc.